# Free Basics Platform(internet.org)

Tags: javascript, php, css, facebook

Free Basics has a policy that you need to disable Javascript code in your website now I have a desktop version website and I want to register it on Free Basics platform should I responsive the same website and disable or hide the Javascript using some Php scripts or css or I have to make a new responsive website with not even a single line of Javascript code? 
help will be much appreciated thanks

Comment: That's a weird policy, considering their website doesn't work correctly without JavaScript - the menu at the top is missing when I disable mine.

Comment: Free hosting is a stepping stone to paid hosting. They always dissallow something so that you end up having to move to paid hosting if you want anything other than a simple HTML brochure-ware site

Comment: so its mean i have to develop another simple html and css base website for registering it on Free Basics?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yeah, but this is not about free hosting for the website owner, but free access for the site visitors, "sponsored" by Facebook and the local carriers they partner up with. These restrictions are not meant to get the site owner to upgrade to any paid plan, but the platform itself is targeted at users in countries with less sophisticated technical infrastructure, largely using feature phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was intrigued and looked at their technical guidelines - did you read those?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/platform-technical-guidelines

You have to have a site that is specifically designed to work on a low-end devices which are not capable (among other things) to run javascript. While you may detect javascript capability, other requirements of this platform are not easily detected, such as the requirement for smaller image sizes etc. After all, the target users for this applications might be in the area where 20 y/o computer on 9kbps modem is considered to be a good machine.

So I'd say that to pass their technical evaluation you will have to create a separate site, that is targeting their needs.

Comment: thats great i got your point , thanks Vladimir